VirtualBox running on: Linux Mint 21.3 VM OS: Windows 7 error: Critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine
Using VirtualBox on: Linux Mint 21.3, kernel: 5.15.0-117-generic Intel© Core™ i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4 memory: 15.6 GB display server: X11 cinnamon: 6.0.4
Virtual OS: Windows 7 base memory: 8192 MB CPU: 2 (of 8) system > processor > Enable PAE/NX = ticked
was working for years, now getting...
error: Critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine
I've links to the vbox.log text file (as its 354.9 kB) https://drive.google.com/file/d/109JsZOEBy6nKMtIXnCVwUxHJ6iZSCFao/view?usp=sharing or https://file.io/1dghD8ZOLC0M or https://filebin.net/3a44jc55m67bz9ox
I'm a total noob as far as VirtualBox errors go, I don't want to do the google > try > break - and make things worse, as I am not technically competent enough to understand what vbox.log is error-ing with.
Can anyone help?
Many thanks, Jay

-> https://forums.virtualbox.org/
VirtualBox 6.1.50 is really old. You really could have upgraded to something more recent and supported. If the OS was in a suspended state, try to delete it and power on fresh.
